# How to prevent the Bootstrap Modal from auto closing?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have bootstrap modal (opened by button) in "Index" View in my ASP.NET MVC web app. In this modal I call stored procedure (with input parameter) which fill three texboxes. After that my modal closes automatically. When I open it again the texboxes are filled. How can I prevent this auto closing?

Part of my "Index" view with stored procedure:

```
<!-- Input parameter to execute stored procedure "GetMesData" -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextBox("send")
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
}

<!-- Textboxes which are fill thanks to stored procedure "GetMesData" -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<br>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserResponse.MatNumber, Model.UserResponse.MatNumber.ToString())<br />
<br>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserResponse.SlurryNumber, Model.UserResponse.SlurryNumber.ToString())<br />
<br>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserResponse.BatchNumber, Model.UserResponse.BatchNumber.ToString())<br />
}
```

JavaScript - probably i should add something here to prevent this auto closing

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

My "Home" controller method post:

```
//Execute stored procedure "GetMesData" with input parameter
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderListOfClass ttt, string send)
{

//calling stored procedure

return View()
}
```